# HTML Displaying the result from server on the same page

Tags: jquery, html

I am completely new to HTML and AJAX /JQuery. I want to display the result of the input as given in the `form` on the same page. 
Below is the code snippet.

```
<div id = "test">
<form id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="/response/">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="name">your text here</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post(
        {
         type:'POST',
         url:$(form).attr('action')
         data: $(form).serialize()
        },
    function(response,status){
        alert("Data: " + resp_final + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

In the above snippet, `resp_final` is the value that is being retrieved from server where `response` is server route where necessary calculation / process is performed. 
This works well. However, the result is being displayed on a separate page. I want to display the result on the same page. 
Can anybody help please?

Comment: Since your button is of default type (`submit`) it will post your form and result will be gathered as new HTML content. You should try to change that button to be like `<button type="button">Submit</button>`.

Comment: Possible values are for "type" attribute of html button:
submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.
(taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else is working ok, the only problem there is the `<button>` type.
Since it has no explicit type, it's working as a submit button (thus, posting the form and redirecting to the response).

Change your button's type to `button` to make it only trigger the associated event handler.

```
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

Here's the possiblem values for a button's type:

submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.

reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.

button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 0):

The js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on('submit', function(e){       
        e.preventDefault();//Will prevent "normal" submission
        $.post(
        {
         type:'POST',
         url:$(this).attr('action'),//"This" refers to the current form
         data: $(this).serialize()
        },
    function(response,status){
        alert("Data: " + resp_final + "\nStatus: " + status);
        //Do something here with the response...
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Chang your code to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data : $(form).serialize(),
      contentType:"application/json",
      success: function(data){
          alert("Data: " + data.resp_final + "\nStatus: " + data.status);
      },
      error: function(jqxhr) {
        alert(jqxhr.responseText); // errors: 324, 500, 404 
      }
  });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead create a `<div id="user_data"></div>` inside `<body>` tag and use bellow scripts to show the server response in the view.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data : $(form).serialize(),
      contentType:"application/json",
      success: function(data){
          $("#user_data").html(data); // show the whole array and (data.index) to select index values)
      },
      error: function(jqxhr) {
        console.log(jqxhr.responseText); 
      }
  });
```

Hint: hope my answer help you.